# Sybase queried through PHP duplicates values

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, sybase

I am currently querying a sybase database using PHP on Windows Server 2012 R2 using ODBC PDO.  When I run a typical select statement, such as "SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U'" it appears to blast an array that puts the last value of the previous key as the first value of the current key, like this:

"[uid] => 101 [2] => 101 [type] => U [3] => U [userstat] => 0 [4] => 0 [sysstat] => 0"

As you can see the "101" element that ends the [uid] index repeats at the beginning of index [2] and the "=> U" at the end of index [2] repeats at the beginning of index [3], and so on - this continues through the whole array blast.  This doesn't seem right - does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and what the solution would be (if this is abnormal?).  If it's helpful I'm including the PHP below:

```
 <?php

 //[BD]---Display All Errors
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 echo "Boom! <br /><br />";

 //[BD]---Try the Connection
 try {

    //Connection Variables
    $dsn = "odbc:Database";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";

    //Connection String
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    //Initiating Error Detection
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );   
 }

 //[BD]---Catch exceptions to the Try
 catch(Exception $e)  {   
    echo "Invalid Connection";
    //Print Error Messages
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
 }  

 //[BD]---SQL Statement(s)

 /* 
 ----------List of Tables---------- 
 */

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U'");

 //[BD]---Execute SQL Statement
 $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      print_r($row);
        echo "<br />";
    }

 echo "<br />Connected Successfully";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.  The keys in the returned array for the row by default contain both the field name and the column number (0 based).  If you only want one or the other you can set the `fetch_style` var to either PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to use only the names as keys, or PDO::FETCH_NUM to index them by column number.

This is the 1st parameter to `fetch` as documented @ http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php